# Loop into the results after a preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php

```
{Hello} {my} {name} {is} {Bob}
```

How can I loop in all the world in between the `{` and `}` ?.

```
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match_all('/{(.*?)\}/s', '{Hello} {my} {name} {is} {Bob}', $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    // Should display Hello, my, name, is, Bob
}
```

Comment: Also helpful: [loop over data extract all email addresses that ends with .co.uk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202946/2943403) and [Extracting numbers from string - Why do I get two arrays when using a capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41276719/2943403) and  [Get specific data from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57198457/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

The captured groups from `preg_match_all()` appear in an array `$matches[1]`.

To get the result you want you can just `implode()` that array...

```
<?php

$matches = array();
$t = preg_match_all('/{(.*?)\}/s', '{Hello} {my} {name} {is} {Bob}', $matches);
echo implode(',',$matches[1]);   //Hello,my,name,is,Bob
```

See: https://3v4l.org/TINmH

If you want to loop over the results use

```
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        // do stuff
    }
```